# Socket IO and Node with HTTPS gives error net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: node.js, laravel, express, socket.io, node-modules

I am Integrating the Socket IO with the Node and Laravel.

I have done the Listeniong of events but ptoblem occurs when i moved my code to server which is HTTPS.

Following it the Error Message:

> GET
>   https://205.186.144.231:3002/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M2NyN1a
>   net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

I have googled many of the solution and make every possible change but not single worked for me.

Following is my Server side code:

**//socket.js**

```
var https = require('https');

var io = require('socket.io')(https);
var fs = require('fs');

var Redis = require('ioredis');
var app = require('express')();

var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('chatMessage');

var options = {
  ca: fs.readFileSync('./public/The_CA_bundle.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('./public/mazau.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./public/mazau.cert'),
};

redis.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    console.log(channel + ' ' + message);
  });

https.createServer(options, app).listen(3002, '205.186.144.231');
console.log('Server running at 205.186.144.231:3002/');
```

and at the Client Side i have done following code:
**//Client Side**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Socket</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('my_socket.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var socket = io('https://205.186.144.231:3002');    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am running the server by Typing **node socket**

I don't know what i have missed. Atleast a single Help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have also went through the same issue. Below I am mentioning the steps which fixed my issue :

```
var app = require('express')();
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var hskey = fs.readFileSync('certs/pri.key');
var hscert = fs.readFileSync('certs/cert.crt');
var ca = fs.readFileSync('certs/ca.crt');

var credentials = {
    ca:ca,
    key: hskey,
    cert: hscert,
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var http = https.createServer(credentials,app);
```

In your case please check whether the path to the key and certificate file is correct. In my case I created a folder where the server js file exists and placed the certificate, key and ca file in it.

Then in your client side, try by providing the domain name instead of the ip address like

```
var socket = io("https://www.yourdomain.com:3002", {secure: true});
```

Restart your node server and check it.